# Dynamic type assignment in Java - Is this a bug in Java?

Tags: java

I was all under the impression that compiler will ensure the type when a `var` keyword in Java is declared and I cannot assign type dynamically based on a condition. But I am not sure if my understanding is wrong or is this a bug in Java. See my below code

```java
public static void printDayOfWeek_new_style(int day) {
        var dayOfTheWeek = switch (day) {
            case 0 -> "Sunday";
            case 1 -> "Monday";
            case 2 -> "Tuesday";

            case 3 -> "Wednesday";
            case 4 -> "Thursday";
            case 5 -> "Friday";
             
            case 6 -> "Saturday";

            default -> 2000;
               
        };
        System.out.println("New >> "+dayOfTheWeek);

        if (dayOfTheWeek instanceof String) {
            System.out.println("yes it is a string");
        }else if (dayOfTheWeek instanceof Integer) {
            System.out.println("yes it is an integer");
        }
                           
   }
```

the `dayOfTheWeek` variable becomes an `Integer` if the switch falls to the `default` statement, whereas the same variable becomes a `String` when it falls in to one the valid `case`s

Is this not something that compiler should catch and why it is even allowed in the first place ? is there a genuine usecase for this ?

Comment: Pro-tip: when you ask "is this a bug in Java" then 99 times out of 100 it's not.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature

Comment: And just for the record: remind yourself about [mcve]. Include actual vs expected output. (I would expect here that the type is always string, and that the compiler turns the 2000 in "2000" ... but yeah, that is just guessing for now). So: if you tested that with say input 0 and input -1, then include the output in your question please.

Comment: Do you expect this to compile: `var output = someBoolean ? "Sunday" : 2000;`?

Comment: the type becomes `Integer` in one case and `String` in another case

Comment: `Object` is also a valid type

Comment: Actually, the inferred type (at least according to my IDE) is `Serializable & Comparable<? extends Serializable & Comparable<?>>`, but the point is it the inferred type doesn’t have to be one of the specific types.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case `var dayOfTheWeek` will be roughly equivalent to `Object dayOfTheWeek`. <sup>*</sup>

So the (static) type of the variable will always be the same: one that can take both an `Integer` and a `String` value, as necessary.

The value it actually *references* during runtime will be *either* a `String` or an `Integer`, depending on the `day` value passed in.

<sup>* Since `String` and `Integer` also share the interfaces `Serializable` and `Comparable` it'll likely be something *like* `Serializable & Comparable<?>` which can't be written as a proper type but `var` doesn't care: it can handle types that you can't write directly in Java. IntelliJ IDEA describes the type as `java.io.Serializable & Comparable<? extends java.io.Serializable & Comparable<?> & java.lang.constant.Constable & java.lang.constant.ConstantDesc> & java.lang.constant.Constable & java.lang.constant.ConstantDesc`, which is quite a mouthful, to be honest.</sup>

Comment: I get it now. This makes sense. so the var is now of a generic type.. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Arun: I'm not sure what you mean by "generic type". If you simply mean "a type that can hold both", then yes. If you mean "a type that uses generics" then you're following a red herring: All that matters is that the real type decided by `var` is a supertype of both `String` and `Integer`. If it was just `Object` it would work as well.

Comment: yeah i got it now.. the var keyword gets a type that is a super-type of both Int and String here. Thanks

Comment: See [JLS § 15.28.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28.1): *" Otherwise, boxing conversion (§5.1.7) is applied to each result expression that has a primitive type, after which the type of the switch expression is the result of applying capture conversion (§5.1.10) to the least upper bound (§4.10.4) of the types of the result expressions."*

Comment: @Arun Integer, not int.